# How to import information from PE_file as binary in C

Tags: c, gcc

I'm making PE file format analyzer in C language.
When I used **Visual Studio**, I could make it much easier.
BUT, I have tired to make it **without Visual Studio** to improve my C programing.
It was made by **GCC**(My laptop is macbook).

To analyze PE file format, as you know I have to use **file pointer** and read file as **'rb'** type.
I did it and it looks like worked well.... I wanted to print first and second words("MZ") but It printed unkown(to me) numbers.

P.S I write little different code refer to previous one to smaller than before. But It print NULL.
It means that I wrote code really wrong... **PLZ tell me which parts are wrong**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// struct to save info of PE_File format
typedef struct _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER 
{
    unsigned short e_magic;
    unsigned short e_cblp;
    unsigned short e_cp;
    unsigned short e_crlc;
    unsigned short e_cparhdr;
    unsigned short e_minalloc;
    unsigned short e_maxalloc;
    unsigned short e_ss;
    unsigned short e_sp;
    unsigned short e_csum;
    unsigned short e_ip;
    unsigned short e_cs;
    unsigned short e_lfarlc;
    unsigned short e_ovno;
    unsigned short e_res[4];
    unsigned short e_oemid;
    unsigned short e_oeminfo;
    unsigned short e_res2[10];
    unsigned long e_lfanew;

} DOS_HEADER;

// I use two different functions.
// First one was made to import PE File format info from file that I used.
// Another was made to print some imformation. I use some comment because I didn't realize those.
DOS_HEADER get_dos_header(FILE *fp, char* fp_buffer);
void print_data_of_structures(DOS_HEADER/*, NT_HEADER, FILE_HEADER, OPTIONAL_HEADER, DATA_DIRECTORY*/);

int main(void)
{
    DOS_HEADER dos_header;

    char file_path[1000];
    printf("Please input your file path : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", file_path);

    FILE* fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen(file_path, "rb");
    if(fp == NULL)
        printf("Unalbe to open file :/\n");

    // To calculate file size.
    long fp_size = 0;
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    fp_size = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    // Declare to use as buffer
    char* fp_buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * (fp_size + 1));

    // Use function to save analyzed information.
    DOS_HEADER info_dos_header = get_dos_header(fp, fp_buffer);

    // Print information.
    print_data_of_structures(info_dos_header);

    fclose(fp);
    free(fp_buffer);

    return 0;
}

DOS_HEADER get_dos_header(FILE* fp, char* fp_buffer)
{
    DOS_HEADER raw_info_dos_header = {0, };

    // Read hex info from fp 2 byte 1 time and save at fp_buffer.
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(fp_buffer, 2, 1, fp);
    raw_info_dos_header.e_magic = fp_buffer;

    return raw_info_dos_header;
}

void print_data_of_structures(DOS_HEADER info_dos_header/*, NT_HEADER info_nt_header, FILE_HEADER info_file_header, OPTIONAL_HEADER info_optional_header, DATA_DIRECTORY info_data_directory*/)
{
    // print info_dos_header
    printf("Print DOS_HEADER\n");
    // I tried several print format(for example %hu, %x, %d) But I coudn't "MZ" or any numbers has realation with "MZ".
    printf("%s", info_dos_header.e_magic);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 big problems with your code: you are mixing types.

In `DOS_HEADER` all members (except the last one) are of type `unsigned short`.
That's important.

In `get_dos_header` you are doing

```
fread(fp_buffer, 2, 1, fp);
raw_info_dos_header.e_magic = fp_buffer;
```

which is wrong.

1. Don't use magic numbers, use `sizeof` to get the correct sizes
2. Check the return value of `fread`, specially if you are analyzing a binary
   format, you must be sure that you've read exactly what you're expecting.
3. It's much easier to deal with `fread` when the `size` argument is 1, because
   only when the `size` argument is 1 the return value of `fread` matches the
   number of bytes read.
4. `e_magic` is a `unsigned short`, `fp_buffer` is a `char*`. This assignment is
   not copying the contents pointed to by `fp_buffer`, you are storing an address
   as if it were a `unsigned short` value. You need to copy the memory pointed to
   by `fp_buffer`.

Also I don't see the point of you allocating a buffer of the size of the file
when you are reading chunk by chunk. It would be easier if you don't allocate a
buffer at all and use an array of a size larger than what you are going to read.

```
int get_dos_header(FILE* fp, DOS_HEADER *dos)
{
    unsigned char buffer[8];

    size_t ret = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(dos->e_magic), fp);

    if(ret != sizeof(dos->e_magic))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid file size\n");
        return 0;
    }

    memcpy(&dos->e_magic, buffer, sizeof(dos->e_magic));

    // DO the others fread operation

    ...

    return 1;
}
```

Then in `main` you can do this:

```
DOS_HEADER raw_info_dos_header = {0, };
if(get_dos_header(fp, &raw_info_dos_header) == 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to get the DOS header\n");
    return 1;
}
...
```

The second problem is in `print_data_of_structures`:

```
printf("%s", info_dos_header.e_magic);
```

`e_magic` is a `unsigned short`, `%s` expects a pointer to `char`, it expects a
string. `e_magic` is definitively not a string. This yield undefined behaviour.
The `printf` should look like this:

```
printf("e_magic: %hu\n", info_dos_header.e_magic);
```

or

```
printf("e_magic: 0x%04hx\n", info_dos_header.e_magic);
```

to print it in hexadecimal format.

I also advice you to use pointers instead. Your struct is big and passing a
pointer to a function is much cheaper than passing a copy of a large struct to a
functions. So instead of

```
void print_data_of_structures(DOS_HEADER info_dos_header);
```

declare it as

```
void print_data_of_structures(DOS_HEADER *info_dos_header);
```

And also don't declare function that can fail (like `get_dos_header`) as
`void`, otherwise how do you tell the calling function that it failed? It's
better for such functions to return an `int` (1 for success, 0 for failure) and
expect a pointer to the struct where the information is stored (see how I
changed `get_dos_header` above.

Comment: Thanks so much. As I said this is my first project made by C language. Conception was easy when I studied myself(e.g. Pointer, Formating or ect). BUT it is really hard to apply at my project. Right, The only way is pratice and pratice.